# When using db.collection('...').add({...}) can bad words appear in the random id?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using firebase firestore for a project and I use the unique id's firestore generates in my URLs. So I was wondering if by using the add operator there might be bad words in the id. I could not find any notes on the firestore documentation that mentions this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ID generation for Cloud Firestore is purely random. So it is indeed possible that a sequence of characters appears in the key that may be offensive or unwanted for another reason.

If this is a concern for your application, you'll have to check the generated IDs in your application code, or use an alternative method to render IDs for new documents that don't have this risk.

Comment: Just to confirm the generated ID cannot generate an id that already exists right?

Comment: The IDs generated by Firestore are statistically guaranteed to be unique.